# How to get a int and a double from an Edit View and display in a Text View? I'm having a hard time to do it...I already solve the int issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, int, textview

These are my xml. I have a EditText and a Text View

```
<TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/resultado"/>

<EditText
                android:id="@+id/a_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Insira a"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="36dp" />
```

My java file. I already converted EditText's value to int, I guess. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class DiagnosticoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagnostico);

        // Get a value from a editText
        EditText editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_edit_text);
        TextView resul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        String variableA = editTextA.getText().toString(); //this will get a string

       int a = 0;
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(variableA);// will only work on numeric entries
            Log.v("DiagnosticoActivity", "Number a: " + a); // this log doesn't work...why?
            resul.setText(""+a);  //Added "" here
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // handle incorrect text entry here
        } // a will be 0 if exception occurred

    }
}
```

How can I display entered number with TextView?

I Tried this but it ain't worked...What I should do?

```
public class DiagnosticoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagnostico);

    }

    public void calcular(View view){
        // Get a value from a editText
        EditText editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_edit_text);
        TextView resul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        String variableA = editTextA.getText().toString(); //this will get a string
        int a = 0;
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(variableA);// will only work on numeric entries
            Log.v("DiagnosticoActivity", "Number a: " + a); // this log doesn't work...why?
            resul.setText(a);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // handle incorrect text entry here
        } // a will be 0 if exception occurred

    }
}


<Button
                android:id="@+id/button_calcular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calcular"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="calcular"/>

<TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/resultado"/>

<EditText
                android:id="@+id/a_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Insira a"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="36dp" />
```

New java code

```
public class DiagnosticoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagnostico);

    }

    public void calcular(View view){
        // Get a value from a editText
        EditText editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_edit_text);
        TextView resul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        String variableA = editTextA.getText().toString(); //this will get a string

        int a = 0;
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(variableA);// will only work on numeric entries
            Log.v("DiagnosticoActivity", "Number a: " + a); // this log doesn't work...why?
            resul.setText(""+a);  //Added "" here
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // handle incorrect text entry here
        } // a will be 0 if exception occurred
    }
}
```

Now I want to get a string to a edit view, cast in a double and display into a text view...But my apps crashs!

```
public class DiagnosticoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editTextA;
    EditText editTextB;
    EditText editTextC;
    EditText editTextD;

    TextView result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagnostico);

        //Locate a View
        editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_edit_text);
        editTextB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b);
        editTextC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.c);
        editTextD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.d);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
    }

    public void calcular(View view){
        // Get a value from a editText
        String variableA = editTextA.getText().toString(); //this will get a string
        String variableB = editTextB.getText().toString(); //this will get a string
        String variableC = editTextC.getText().toString(); //this will get a string
        String variableD = editTextD.getText().toString(); //this will get a string

        //Cast a String in a int or double
        double a = Double.parseDouble(variableA);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(variableB);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(variableC);
        int d = Integer.parseInt(variableD);

        double soma = a;

        result.setText("" + soma);

        /*double soma = a/b;
        String finalresult = new Double(soma).toString();
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        finalresult= nf.format(result);
        textView1.setText(finalresult);*/

        /*
        double soma = a/b;
        String stringDouble= Double.toString(soma);
        result.setText("" + stringDouble);*/

        /*int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(variableA);// will only work on numeric entries
            b = Integer.parseInt(variableB);// will only work on numeric entries
            Log.v("DiagnosticoActivity", "Number a: " + a);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            a = 0; // handle incorrect text entry here
        } // a will be 0 if exception occurred*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DiagnosticoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editTextA;
TextView resul;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagnostico);
    editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_edit_text);
    resul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
}

public void calcular(View view){
    // Get a value from a editText

    String variableA = editTextA.getText().toString(); //this will get a string
    resul.setText(variableA);

    int a = 0;
    try {
        a = Integer.parseInt(variableA);// will only work on numeric entries
        Log.v("DiagnosticoActivity", "Number a: " + a); // this log doesn't work...why?
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       a = 0; // handle incorrect text entry here
    } // a will be 0 if exception occurred
}
}
```

Comment: You're a genius! IT WORKED!!! Let me understand the algoritm...Can you explain me what I was doing wrong? THANK YOU!

Comment: Not a big thing. The problem with this statement only. resul.setText(a);
Getting a EditText's  input as String converting to int and again converting it to String to display on TextView. Instead of this we can show directly fetched String(from EditText).

Comment: I'm suggesting you to try and execute examples for your needed topics rather than trying it by yourself. It can help you to get good basic knowledge of android and android programming.

Comment: One question. The number showed is a String or int? Is this should display a instead variableA. Do am I right?

Comment: Do one favor. I'll delete all my answers except this one. You delete your error logs and everything. Keep only xml and java code.

Comment: It showed as a String in this case. Yeah you are right. It's showing by variableA String.

Comment: Thanks! Later on I will get two numbers from a edit text, add each other and display in th text view.... This code will work?

Comment: Yeah it will work. Instead of one EditText and TextView you need to keep two EditTexts and one or two TextViews to display.

Comment: If you face any difficulties comment here. I'll be get notified. I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks man! I will stop for today... I spent 10 hours to fix this...My head is spinning... I let you know whats going on... I fixed my question like you said, I deleted all the error message

Comment: Fine. Have a nice day. Happy Coding ;)

Comment: Ajith, good morning! Man, I got how to get two strings from a edit view, cast in a int, add each other and display in a tex view. Now I want to get these numbers, casting in dou ble and show them in a text view, but my apps crashs.... can show you?